# How to print html template to printer without viewing it

Tags: c#, asp.net, .net, angularjs, printing

Here's an example of a html template with css, I want to send it to a printer without the help of the WebBrowser Control as my application is mvc anf angularjs and it's dedicated to web forms.

```
 <html>
<body>
<div>
<p font-size:4 >
Test printing a html template.
</p>
</div>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: while searching i found too many people recommend using WebBrowser to print html template , so i said that i need another solution.

Comment: I want to print a html template from MVC application , this html template is sent as string contains the template